# How to apply patches to apache?

Tags: apache2, patch

I am trying to apply patches to apache. The current version of apache is 2.2.22 and using ubuntu server 12.04 LTS. we have installed apache using apt-get command. I have downloaded patch from [here](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/patches/apply_to_2.2.9/). I am not sure where to put this file. I have put the patch file under /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ and used below command to apply patch.

patch -s < mod_proxy_ftp_CVE-2008-2939.diff

It again asked me to enter File to Patch :

```
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|# SECURITY: CVE-2008-2939 (cve.mitre.org)
|# mod_proxy_ftp: Prevent XSS attacks when using wildcards in the path of
|# the FTP URL. Discovered by Marc Bevand of Rapid7.
|Index: modules/proxy/mod_proxy_ftp.c
|===================================================================
|--- modules/proxy/mod_proxy_ftp.c      (Revision 682869)
|+++ modules/proxy/mod_proxy_ftp.c      (Revision 682870)
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

I entered same file name : mod_proxy_ftp_CVE-2008-2939.diff

It is giving me below error

```
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file mod_proxy_ftp_CVE-2008-2939.diff.rej
```

I am not sure what is wrong here ? Am I doing anything wrong ? I have tried google whole day.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Patches are to be applied against the source code not the binaries. You patch the source code and the compile it.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, can you please help me with any guide or link ? where I can do this from scratch. I am very new to this kind of stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to aplly a patch for the `modules/proxy/mod_proxy_ftp.c` file which is a source file.

If you *really* want to do that, you need to download the source code of apache, apply the patch and recompile apache.

Comment: Thanks @Mali. I was not aware of this, as I am doing this for the first time. I downloaded the source from apache and then I was able to apply patch.